# Docker Image Deployment In K8's Pod not happening

Tags: docker, kubernetes-helm

Docker Image: -

```
docker images | grep -i "gcc"
gcc-docker                                                                            latest                  84c4359e6fc9        21 mites ago      1.37GB

docker run -it gcc-docker:latest
hello,world
```

Kubernetes pod deployed:-

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age        From                  Message
  ----     ------     ----       ----                  -------
  Normal   Scheduled  <unknown>  default-scheduler     Successfully assigned default/hello-world to master-node
  Normal   Pulling    4s         kubelet, master-node  Pulling image "gcc-docker:latest"
  Warning  Failed     0s         kubelet, master-node  Failed to pull image "gcc-docker:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Erroresponse from daemon: pull access denied for gcc-docker, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested acce to the resource is denied
  Warning  Failed     0s         kubelet, master-node  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    0s         kubelet, master-node  Back-off pulling image "gcc-docker:latest"
  Warning  Failed     0s         kubelet, master-node  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

-->yaml files used to deploy pod

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hello-world
  labels:
    type: hello-world
spec:
  containers:
  - name: hello-world
    image: gcc-docker:latest
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo Hello Kubernetes! && sleep 60']
    ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: Your question description does not have sufficient details. Please add details to help others understand what you are looking for.

Comment: I have created a sample hello world program in docker environment. have the docker image for the same, trying to deploy in kubernet pod. the deployment is failing with the above error which i have pasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried pulling gcc-docker and got the same error.You may have this image present on your system already and now its not on dockerhub.

[image]

if you know the repository for this image, try to use the same and for authentication create secrets of docker type and use them as image pull secrets.

Also, one more thing you are running the container on the master node, and I assume it's minikube or some local setup.
Minikube uses a dedicated VM to run Kubernetes which is not the same as the machine on which you have installed minikube.

So images available on your laptop will not be available to minikube.

Comment: After changing the name from gcc-docker to anyother name pod started up & running.